# Basic http authentication from browser to server via socket

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am trying to write a simple java server that receives HTTP GET requests from web browser and sends back some data. All the communication is done via sockets.

I am able to process the requests and now I am trying to implement a simple authentication with BASIC AUTH so some requests will be handled only if correct credentials are provided in the request header. For sake of simplicity, I am using only http protocol (not https). I am not sure how to access the header and read the credentials on my server, though:

The server runs on localhost, port 9000 and this is the sample URL that I am trying to process:

```
http://user:password@localhost:9000/files/text?tid=file3
```

I open the socket and read everything:

```
InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

// Reading line by line with a BufferedReader
java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new String line;
while (!(line = in.readLine()).equals("")) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This is what I get:

```
GET /files/text?tid=file3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

There is no trace of the auth credentials I put in the URL so I am not sure how to parse the request. Could you tell me what am I missing here?

I know that this example is very simple and there are more clever ways to implement this but I am curious how to access these credentials in this simple model case.

Comment: You write "There is no trace of the auth credentials I put in the URL". That's not how Basic Auth works. The client must set the `Authorization` header.

Comment: I thought that the header is set basically by adding the credentials in the url: user:password@rest_of_the_url

Comment: Your server needs to tell the browser that it requires authentication. Just sticking things into the URL won't make the browser encode and send them. Especially since this is over HTTP. See [this example](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml). Your server **must** respond with a request for credentials. At this point, the browser will attempt to retrieve the credentials and send them to the server.

Comment: @Smajl: To elaborate on Boris' comment, your web server needs to look at the request, and if the `Authentication` header is missing or specifies invalid credentials then send a [`401`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.2) response, including a [`WWW-Authenticate`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.47) header specifying the authentication scheme(s) the server supports and their expected parameters (in this case, `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myrealm"` - see [RFC 2617](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a client like [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

```
$ curl -v -u user:password "http://localhost:9000/files/text?tid=file3"
```

Since HTTP is stateless, sending the `Authentication` header is enough. That's what `curl` does. It is not necessary to wait for the server to return a `401`.

Comment: The one with curl works. Is there a way how to make it work with browser as well?